# Controlling the adjoint variables in a stochastically perturbed control problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have a deterministic control problem

$$dX_t = b(X_t, u_t) \, dt$$

on a finite timeframe with no terminal cost; i.e. the objective functional to be maximised is

$$\mathbb E \left [\int_{0}^T f(t, X_t, u_t) \, dt \right].$$

Here $b, f$ may be assumed as smooth as desired, and the control process $u$ is assumed to take values in the closure of some bounded open set in Euclidean space. The state variable $X$ is assumed to take values in $\mathbb R^d$, with deterministic initial condition $x_0 \in \mathbb R^d$. We assume also the existence of a unique optimal control for the problem.

Consider, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ the stochastically perturbed problem

$$dX^{\varepsilon}_t = b(X^\varepsilon_t, u_t) \, dt + \varepsilon \, dW_t,$$

with the same initial condition and objective functional, where $W$ is a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion.

Denote by $p, p^{\varepsilon}$ the (first order) adjoint variables for the deterministic and stochastic problems respectively.

**Question:** Can we control the size of $p - p^\varepsilon$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$? For example, can we show that

$$\mathbb E[\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T} |p_t - p^{\varepsilon}_t|] \to 0$$

as $\varepsilon \to 0$?

*Note: Here the adjoint variables refer to those in the statement of the (stochastic) maximum principle. For concreteness, the version I will be using is Theorem 3.2 (page 118) in Yong and Zhou’s book, Stochastic Controls. Due to length constraints I am unable to reproduce the full definitions here.*